# Recuperar una base de datos despues de borrar MYSQL Server?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, tablas, data

Tenia unas 3 webs hechas con wordpress en Local. Hize un backup de 2 de ellas, porque iba a desinstalar el MYSQL Server para no perder nada. Resulta que una vez desinstalé el MYsql Server me di cuenta que habia una BD de la cual no había hecho ningun backup. Rebuscando llegé a una carpeta MYSQL Server 5.0 en archivos de programa, donde dentro de otra carpeta data había una carpeta con el nombre de la base de datos y sus respectivos archivos (como adjunto en la imagen).

He vuelto a instalar el MYSQL Server 5.7 y poner la carpeta de esa base de datos en la carpeta donde estan las bases de datos MYSQL Server 5.7, pero resulta que no se ponen bien. Ahora al acceder a esa base de datos el MYSQL me dice que "table wordpress.wp_users" no existe, eso con todas las tablas, y no hay manera.

Además cuando voy a localhost/nombreweb me vuelve a pedir el titulo del sitio y el correo para instalar wordpress, cuando ya lo tenía instalado de anteriormente.

Que podría hacer? Hay alguna solución para recuperar esa Base de datos?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

PD: solo tengo esos 2 tipos de archivos, frm y opt. He probado con otra instalación de wordpress y nada. Imposible. Siempre me dice que las tablas no existen.

Comment: Mira las respuestas a [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/879176/5587982).

Comment: Muchas gracias. Mira que habia leido cosas, pero nunca había leido ese post. Lo que me faltaba por copiar era el archivo data ese. Solo copiaba los .frm y odp. Solucionado..